# What should I do with the loop variable to increase it by 1 per loop in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I tried the example:
 `loop = $(($loop + 1))`

but Linux Shell have told me

> ./while_and_read.sh: line 17: loop: command not found

What should I do with the loop vairable to increase it by 1 per loop in Linux Shell?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please type a number which it should be greeter than 0."

read -p "Number:" -t 5 x

sum=0
loop=0

if [ $x -le 0 ];then
 echo "Please type a number which it should be greeter than 0."
 else

  while [ $loop -le $x ]
   do
     echo "The variable value of now loop is $loop."
     loop = $(($loop + 1))
     exit
    # sum = $(($sum+$loop))
   done

  echo "The final result is $sum."
fi
```

Comment: copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix the syntax errors highlight. (You need to include `#!/bin/bash` as the first line). If its still not working after those fixes, update your Q with the corrected code and include the new error messages. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for assigning values to variables in bash does not accept spaces around the `=` sign.

In your case, replace that line with `loop=$(($loop +1))`.

Comment: The assignment can even be done inside the arithmetic expression. In this case spaces around `=` are accepted. `((loop=loop + 1))` or `((loop = loop + 1))` or `((loop++))`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you ask but you can use a brace expansion (*) range for the same purpose:

```
for loop in $(eval echo "{0..$x}");
do
 echo "$loop"
done
```

*: [Brace expansion](https://linuxhint.com/bash_brace_expansion/) will work with bash (as the shebang states).

The `echo` + `eval` is required because brace expansion does not work with variables.

You could use a simpler version with `zsh` (that supports variables on brace expansion):

```
for loop in {0..$x};
do
 echo "$loop"
done
```

Comment: The question is tagged `[linux][shell]` meaning POSIX shell. The *brace-expansion* `{0..$x}` is not defined by POSIX. See [Bashism - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)

Comment: You are correct. It is only for `bash`. I got confused by the `shebang` on the example.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, though personally I would prefer `$(seq 0 "$x")` -- it's shorter and safer.